# Выборочный парсинг данных из Excel файлa

Tags: python, pandas, excel, обработка-данных

Есть Excel файл с данными, 5 столбцов. Нужно спарсить выборчные колонки.

Вот столбцы `['Name', 'Age', 'position', 'level', 'city']`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_ = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=['sheet1', 'sheet2'])
df = pd.DataFrame().append([df_[i] for i in df_]).reset_index(drop=True)
column_name = ['Name', 'city']

data = []
for i in range(len(column_name)):
    data.append(df[column_name[i]])


print(data)
```

Нужно получить данные с `Name` и с `City`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметрами [pd.read_excel(..., sheet_name=['sheet1', 'sheet2'], usecols=["Name","city"])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, 
                             sheet_name=['sheet1', 'sheet2'], 
                             usecols=['Name', 'city']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем всё так сложно? Просто берёте нужные колонки из `DataFrame`:

```
data = df[column_name]
```